# Matlab different function over different intervals

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement

I would like the function y to be zero if temp is less than 0.5 and exp(x) otherwise.
However what i tried below just sets all of y to zero. Any suggestions?

```
x = 0:.01:2;
tmp = x.^2;

if tmp<0.5
  y= exp(x);
else
  y= 0;
end
plot(x,y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `y` to `exp(x)` and then use logical indexing to set `y` to zero where `tmp` is less than `0.5`:

```
y = exp(x);
t(tmp < 0.5) = 0;
```

Also if `y` doesn't exist in the matlab seesion yet then you can do it in one step like this:

```
y(tmp >= 0.5) = exp(x(tmp >= 0.5)
```

and the zeros will be filled in automatically. But personally I prefer the first way.